# google tag maneger with custom javascript event

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a javascript code for pushing an event with diffrent action to data layer for google tagmaneger.In google tag maneger i have a tag for google analytic with my custom event and all action.Which is working very good.But now i want to create another tag with same custom event but this time with only one specific action.but my both tag is firing for same time.event with specific action also firing .I will be very appreciate for a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [trigger exceptions](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679318?hl=en).

Essentially if the trigger is TRUE/Will trigger, it will prevent the tag from triggering.

If you provide more information on exactly what you want to trigger on, event names, etc I can provide more implementation details.